# How to set a Folder Watcher as a Trigger in Flogo

Tags: iot, tibco

I have an use case for reading a File on the arrival of the File in a directory. For this I am thinking of setting a Trigger which listens to the arrival of a file in a predefined folder and reading the contents of the file as the subsequent action. How can I achieve this using TIBCO Project Flogo? Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Surya